# Draft mailings showing as blank screen

Tags: civimail, civicrm-spark

I'm using CiviCRM Spark and when I go to copy a previously sent mailing to make a new copy and click edit, it only brings up a blank screen and not a copy of the previous mailing to edit and work from like it used to. Anyone else experienced this error?

Thanks!

Comment: hi - could you email spark@civicrm.org with the name/URL of your CiviCRM instance? I am a CiviCRM Spark admin and will have a look.